# Block or variable definition of integer and memory capacity

Tags: fortran, fortran-common-block

Does anyone have idea about this problem ,
I have a code that runs nicely for 3000 element mesh 
But when I want to run it for 17000 element mesh it shows me this error:
A common block or variable may not exceed 2147483647 bytes

This is some parts of code:

```
PARAMETER(NDIM=398316702)

integer   IA(NDF+1),LPIVTC(NDF),JA(NDIM)

DIMENSION AA(NDIM)
```

And it shows the error for

```
DIMENSION AA(NDIM)
```

Why is it in that way?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a characteristic of Fortran per se, but rather your particular compiler or operating system.  Note that 2147483647 = 2^31 - 1 or 2 gigabits.   Probably you have a 32-bit OS and it is unable to allocate larger amounts of memory.   As to why you can't get a full 2^32, perhaps something is using a signed rather than unsigned integer to store addresses and one bit is unavailable.

Comment: but u know the problem is with AA and it's definition
i mean if I define AA in this way ,that problem is solved

Real AA(NDIM)

but if i define it as: DIMENSION AA(NDIM) then there is a problem